# Creating shockwave vector in Gimp

Tags: gimp, vector, procedural-art

Being completely new to Gimp, I can't seem to create something like this:
[image]

Any direction on how to proceed?

I started out with creating a circle with ellipse select tool, then filling it with brush stroke, and then proceeded to manually create those radial spikes using a brush with basic dynamics, with a fade. Spent nearly an hour, but the strokes didn't come out as expected, so deleted the gimp project and came here to ask. Is there a better way to achieve this, preferably procedurally... Please Advise.... Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You are basically asking us you help you recreate an image that is clearly copyright. To be honest, I don't feel this is appropriate here. Sorry about that.  Perhaps you should consider buying the image instead.

Comment: If you need vector.. GIMP is the wrong tool.